# Chapter book where a scientist with lung cancer is abducted by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, childrens-novel

I'm struggling trying to remember a book from my 3rd grade class (1993–94.) I bought it at my school book fair so it was age appropriate for grade school level.

It was a chapter book about a scientist who gets lung cancer. The scientist got the cancer from breathing in dust or debris from a project he was working on, not from smoking. He looks for a cure, is about to give up and then aliens abduct him and take him away to treat him.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, **when (what year) did you read this book?** What was the scientist's name? How old was he? What caused his lung cancer (was he a smoker, for instance)? What cures had he looked for? What did the aliens look like? How did they get to Earth? How did they abduct him? Did they return him to Earth after they'd cured him? Why did they want to cure him?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this (approximate year)?  We don't know when you were in 3rd grade.

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Robert-J-Sawyer/dp/0812580354?

Comment: Yeah of course, it would have been around 1993,94. I really wish I could remember specifics of the book. One thing I could add was that the scientists acquired the cancer from breathing in dust or debris from w project he was working on,  not from smoking.

Comment: Also, I bought it at my school book fair so it was age appropriate for grade school level

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to [Calculating God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_God) by Robert J. Sawyer. It isn't a chapter book, but it has the plot elements you describe. The protagonist *Thomas Jericho* is a palaeontologist and he does get cancer from breathing in dust from his work:

> I’ve never smoked. So why do I have lung cancer?
>
> It’s actually, so I’ve learned, somewhat common among paleontologists, geologists, and mineralogists of my generation. I was right, in a way, when I attributed my cough to the dusty environment I worked in. We often use tools that pulverize rocks, creating a lot of fine dust, which ...
>
> But lung cancer takes a long time to develop, and I’ve been working in paleontology labs for thirty years. These days, I almost always wear a mask; our consciousness has been raised, and almost everyone does so when doing that kind of work. But, still, over the decades, I’d breathed in more than my share of rock dust, not to mention asbestos fibers as well as fiberglass filaments while making casts. And now I’m paying for it.

At the end of the book he does leave Earth with an alien called *Hollus* who is a member of a race called the *Forhilnor*. But this isn't in search of a cure - the aliens do get cancer and their treatments are not much more advanced than human medicine.

Also the book was published in 2000, so unless you've misremembered the date or conflated the details with this book it's too late to be the book you read in 1993/4. It's always possible that Sawyer had read your book and that inspired him to write *Calculating God*.

Comment: Given how much of a slog it was to read as an adult, I can't imagine a 9-year-old lasting through a hundred pages of waffling about intelligent design.  (This and *Hominids* are what stopped me reading Sawyer.)

Comment: @DavidW It seems a long shot, but no-one else has answered so it's worth a try.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't have posted it as an answer, I just felt that caveat should be noted.

Comment: I spotted this, but felt that it was much too late and much too wordy to be the book in the question.